# How to check a form is submitted or other links are clicked in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently i have a $(window).unload function which do some tasks on leaving that page. but i need these actions to be done only if a form is not submitted. This is what i have done so far`

```
$(window).unload(function () {
    var flag=0;  
       $("#id-message-form").submit(function(){
           flag=1;
       });
      if(flag!=1){
            $.ajax({
                url: "app/ajax_handler.php",
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                data:{},
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                complete: function() {

                },     
                success: function(data)  {

                }
            });
    }
});`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a flag when a form is submitted - and then check that in your unload function.

```
// Set this globally
var formSubmit = false;

$('form').on('submit', function() {
    formSubmit = true;
}
```

Then in your window unload function;

```
if(!formSubmit) {
    // your code that submits the form
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the scope of the `flag` variable and the `submit` handler. Place them outside the `unload` handler. I'd also suggest changing `flag` to a boolean value.

```js
var formSubmitted = false;

$("#id-message-form").submit(function() {
  formSubmitted = true;
});

$(window).unload(function() {
  if (!formSubmitted) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "app/ajax_handler.php",
      type: 'GET',
      data: {},
      async: false,
      beforeSend: function() {},
      complete: function() {},
      success: function(data) {}
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `submit()` will no matter submit the form by default. You should try `click()` function to store flag value instead.